# How to find the difference between two times in Android / Java?

Tags: java, android, datetime, timertask, date-difference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

i have two date values in two textboxes in string datatypes in HH:MM:SS format.HOw can i find difference between them and get result in HH:MM:SS?please help me...as fast as possible....!

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Sample/ expected input/output?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: What is not working? Are they not comparing as it should? Code looks completely fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
     format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     try {
         Date date1 = (Date) format.parse("4:15:20");
         Date date2 = (Date) format.parse("2:30:30");
         //time difference in milliseconds
         long timeDiff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); 
         //new date object with time difference
         Date diffDate = new Date(timeDiff); 
         //formatted date string
         String timeDiffString = format.format(diffDate); 
         System.out.println("Time Diff = "+ timeDiffString );
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Above code has certain limitations. Other proper way could be to convert the long value of time difference manually in the string as below:

```
     long timeDiffSecs = timeDiff/1000;
     String timeDiffString = timeDiffSecs/3600+":"+
                             (timeDiffSecs%3600)/60+":"+
                             (timeDiffSecs%3600)%60;
     System.out.println("Time Diff = "+ timeDiffString);
```

Comment: its not working...frend..:(

Comment: @jims What is not working? Do highlight the issue. Both the above code snippets are working code. I validated it before posting. First one has some limitation which I already mentioned.

Comment: The second solution is the best one, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will give you the number of milliseconds difference between the listed dates. It could be that the answer could be simply divide by 1000 to get the number of seconds.

Comment: Sir,i have two times in HH:MM:SS format,now i want to substract the time1 from time2 and want to get result in HH:MM:SS format...can u please help?

Answer (score 0):

First Convert String date into simple Date formate

```
public String getconvertdate1(String date)
{
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date parsed = new Date();
    try
    {
        parsed = inputFormat.parse(date);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);
    return outputText;
}
```

> //now can do anything with date.

```
 long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
 long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);// you get day difference between
```

> AND use simpledateFormate to configure HH:MM:SS

Comment: sir,problem is that i've both the times are in String formate....Please help me..:(

Comment: @jims i have edited my answer you date formate string first convert them...

Comment: 12-25 09:00:56.537: W/System.err(1642): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date.............

Comment: ctr+shift+O press and select java.util.Date not java.sql.Date.

Comment: tnx altaf...done it...thank u...:)